# Prove that $[G\times H : A\times B]=[G:A][H:B]$ when $A < G$ and $B < H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

The original question is that:

> If $A$ is subgroup of group $G$ and $B$ is a subgroup of group $H$, then express $[G\times H : A\times B]$ in terms of $[G:A]$ and $[H:B]$ and **prove the result is correct!**

I first prove $A\times B < G\times H$ then use Lagrange's theorem to write it as $[G\times H : A\times B]=[G:A][H:B]$... (is it correct?) But I really have no idea about how to prove my result.

Should I prove things like "If $[G\times H : A\times B]=[G:A][H:B]$ then  $A < G$ and $B < H$"?

Thanks!

---

Well..I guess I misunderstood what it wants me to do...

Comment: A<B? It should be A<G..

Comment: So I just need to show details about how I get to [GxH : AxB]=[G:A][H:B]?...

Comment: Yes, exactly!${}{}{}$, Yes, you're right, it should be $A\leq G$!

Comment: Well I misunderstood what the question wants me to do...Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

From comments, expanded here:

No, you're *given* that $A≤G$ and $B≤H.$

You use *those* facts to express $[G×H:A×B]\;$ in terms of $\;[G:A]$ and $[H:B],\;$ and then prove that the expression that you think holds FOLLOWS FROM the premises $\;A\leq G,\;B\leq H$.

You've made a good hypothesis: $$[G\times H : A\times B]=[G:A][H:B]\;\;?$$

Now see what you can do to prove it, given $A\leq G, \;B\leq H$.

Feel free to follow up in a comment if you get stuck.

Comment: Did you manage to prove the hypothesis? I hope this all helped clear us the task. I moved the "extended comment" to a post ;-)